# GeoNode change uploaded directory path

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, geonode

I am new to GeoNode. I installed GeoNode stable version from `apt-get install geonode` on Ubuntu 14, and its working properly. Now I want to change the uploaded directory to `/home/user/uploaded`

I changed `MEDIA_ROOT` path in `local_settings.py` and uploaded allies in `etc/apache2/sites-available/geonode.conf` but once a layer uploaded in `base_link` PostgreSQL table, the thumbs URL still stored as the original GeoNode uploaded path.

How can I change it to every new upload?
Or else is there any other way to change the uploaded directory path in GeoNode 2.4

I already searched way to change the GeoNode uploaded directory path, but I did not found a way.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, To change uploaded directory to /home/user/uploaded, you have to change **MEDIA_ROOT** path in local_settings.py and **uploaded** allies in /etc/apache2/sites-available/geonode.conf, then to give permission to access that directory, we have to change **apache2.conf** file.

Open apache2.conf file

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

and add this

```
<Directory /home/user/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        #Require all denied
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now your new uploaded will store in new directory.